# How to change a int number to the asci equivalent?

Tags: java, arrays, ascii, minesweeper

I´m making and Minesweeper in a matrix of 5x5. I made the random assignation of the mines and also made the sensors for the mines, its working ok i think.

```
public Minesweeper(){

        matrix = new int [5][5];    
int minesnumber = (int)(Math.random()*10);
            for(int mines = 0 ; mines < minesnumber ; mines ++){
              int i, j;//Coordinates in the array
              do{
                  i = (int)(Math.random()*5);//random values to i and j
                  j = (int)(Math.random()*5);
              }while(matrix[i][j] == minesnumber );
              matrix[i][j] = 64;//ascii = @

              for(int a = Math.max(0, i-1); a < Math.min(5,i+2); a++){// to work on the array only
                  for(int b = Math.max(0,j-1); b < Math.min(5,j+2); b++){
                      if(matrix[a][b] != 64 && matrix[a][b]<9){// not a bomb
                          matrix[a][b]++;}
                       }
                     }
                    }
                   }
                 }
```

My main is for printing the minesweeper

```
public static void main(String args[]){

Minesweeper matrix = new Minesweeper();


for(int i = 0 ; i<5 ; i++){
    System.out.println("\n ======================================");
    for(int j = 0 ; j<5 ; j++){
        int [][]m = matrix.getMatrix();
      System.out.print("| "  +  m[i][j]   + " | ");
    }
}
System.out.println("\n ======================================");

}
```

It shows the 64 of the bombs and the number fo the sensor of bombs, i would like to conver the 64 to  '@', i think of using `Character.toChars(64)`

So when i print the minesweeper, i can see the mines detectors and the @

But i dont know where to use it.
Or if someone know an simplier way?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make the matrix an array of `char` type to begin with? They behave like integers when it comes to math, but will print as characters to the screen.

Otherwise, you want `System.out.print("| "  +  (char)(m[i][j])   + " | ");`. You simply need to cast the integer to a char for the string to concatenate properly. Additionally, you can assign the mines to the matrix as `(int)('@')` to make your code clearer.

Both of these methods are kinda sloppy. If I were to implement minesweeper, I'd make a separate tile class with a field indicating if it contains a bomb, or how far away it is from a bomb, and if it contains a flag. For a first go, however, your method is fine.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply cast `int` to `char`.

```
char ascciVal=(char)intVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following statement.

```
char ascciChar= (char)64;
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following to show ascii char:

```
int yourInt = 64;
char ch = (char) yourInt;
System.out.println(ch);
```